# Material UI React Table: Applying Left and Right Padding

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to apply padding in a Material UI 4 React table, so all the actual text, starts at the green lines (within the blue gray outline box). How can this be done? I was trying to style padding, however it was not working.

[image]

Comment: can you please share some code, so that we can help you. Mean time you can try adding padding to 1st Column using `className`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply `border-collapse: separate`, `padding-left: <length>` and `padding-right: <length>` (or their shorthand equivalent) directly to the `<table>` element. You can target the `<table>` element directly by using the [sx property](https://v4.mui.com/system/basics/#sx-property) on the MuiTable component or by using the global class name for the [MuiTable component](https://v4.mui.com/api/table/#css) which is: **.MuiTable-root**. (In fact, there are many options for applying styling to Material-UI components. I'm just presenting two of them to keep things simple.) In my sample below I use both (although it isn't necessary to add the global class name within the sx property; I just added it there to add specificity to the CSS selector).

Using `border-collapse: separate` can significantly change the layout of your table. You may also have to apply `border-spacing` (again, using *sx* or the *.MuiTable-root* class) to `<table>`. Consider this notice from [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) about *border-spacing*:

> The border-spacing value is also used along the outside edge of the table, where the distance between the table's border and the cells in the first/last column or row is the sum of the relevant (horizontal or vertical) border-spacing and the relevant (top, right, bottom, or left) padding on the table.

---

Directly from the [MUI docs](https://v4.mui.com/components/tables/#basic-table), here is code for a Basic Table:

```js
  ...
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            ...
```

### Sample

You can edit the line with the opening tag to the `<Table>` component to add left and right gaps like this:

```js
      <Table
        className={classes.table}
        aria-label="simple table"
        sx={{
          ['&.MuiTable-root']: {
            paddingLeft: '16px', // or whatever the desired gap.  
            paddingRight: '16px', // or whatever the desired gap.
            borderCollapse: 'separate'
          }
        }}
      >
```